# What is wrong with noskipws?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having trouble with the following template function.

```
/// Remove leading and trailing space and tab characters from a string.
/// @param[out] result  the string to remove leading and trailing spaces from
template<class T>
void TrimString(std::basic_string<T>& str)
{
    basic_string<T> s, strRslt;

    basic_stringstream<T> strstrm(str);

    // we need to trim the leading whitespace using the skipws flag from istream.
    strstrm >> s;

    if(!s.empty())
    {
        do
        {
            strRslt += s;
        }while(strstrm >> noskipws >> s);
    }


    str = strRslt;

    return;

}
```

This Unit test passes:

```
[TestMethod]
void TestNarrowStringTrim()
{
    std::string testString = "    test";
    TrimString(testString);
    Assert::IsTrue(testString == "test");
}
```

So I would also expect the following unit test to pass:

```
[TestMethod]
void TestNarrowStringTrim()
{
    std::string testString = "    test string";
    TrimString(testString);
    Assert::IsTrue(testString == "test string");
}
```

However, for some reason, the value of str at the end of the function is "test"

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Because it is probably (almost certainly) relevant, I am using Visual C++ with Visual Studio 2012.

The MSDN article for noskipws differs from the ccpreference.com article as well. I have linked both articles for comparison.

[MSDN noskipws](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ttf4txbf(v=vs.110)/)

[cppreference.com noskipws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it made me choke for a second, I just checked my actual code, and thankfully, it looks like that is a copy/paste error into the question text, I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a string from a stream stops when it encounters a space. As you have disabled skipws the first character read is a space. Therefore an empty string is read and failbit is set. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt.

The VS 2012 implementation is probably correct (your code fails with gcc too) just the documentation is poor.

There is no need to use streams at all, find and substr is much simpler:

```
template<class T>
void TrimString( std::basic_string<T>& str)
{
    size_t begin = str.find_first_not_of(" \t");
    if ( begin == std::string::npos )
    {
        str.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        size_t end = str.find_last_not_of(" \t");
        str = str.substr( begin, end - begin + 1 );
    }
}
```

Or even simpler is `boost::trim()`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id-1.3.3.5.5

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the find_first_not_of(" \t") will work because I have to work with std::string and std::wstring.

I was hoping to find a solution that didn't require two specializations of the template, but for now, I guess I'll just write them.
Thanks!

Comment: @Catachan : That isn't a problem as `'\n'` will widen into `L'\n'`; it's only a problem if you need to look for a non-ASCII character and thus have to deal with encodings.